# Get path of Java application that launched the executable

Tags: java, c++, linux

I am trying to validate that only our Java application has launched an inside-included executable. To achieve this, I thought of having a list of valid known SHA2 hashes (of the Java application) on our server and the executable will first check if the application's hash it was launched from is on that list.

So far, everything is working. The hashing, client-server communication etc. Except I have stumbled at the last hurdle. I am unable to get the path of the Java application from the executable.

I thought I could simply do this:

```
pid_t jarpid = getppid();

// Got from online
int get_exe(pid_t pid, char* buf, size_t bufsize) {
    char path[64];
    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/exe", pid);
    return readlink(path, buf, bufsize);
}
```

However this points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java and not the running Java Application. I do use the ProcessBuilder in the application to launch the executable.

So my question is, how can I get the applications path that launched the executable. Is it even possible? I cannot provide the executable with arguments, as that would be too easy to reverse engineer.

Comment: Why is it important that only the Java app launch it? Can you make it a native  library and use JNI?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It is a license system, that validates the product is licensed before secretly downloading and executing the real jar before deleting it. It is necessary that a Java program executes it as it's for a Minecraft Server plugin.

Comment: You already have it. The Java executable. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I need to get the path of the application that launched a executable (from inside the executable). I cannot use arguments in the executable.